# Formula that uses value from ActiveX Combo Box not updating

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, activex

I have an ActiveX combo box that allows the user to select a year. The year chosen then populates in cell D2 (the linked cell). The formula in D3 should then automatically adjust based on the data value (year) in cell D2. However, cell D3 does not automatically adjust when D2 changes. I have to double-click D2 for the formula in D3 to recalculate. I’ve used:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change ()
  Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_AfterUpdate ()
  Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

And others but nothing works.

Comment: I've tested this and can't reproduce your issue.  For me, with calculation set to Auto, D3 updates (and no events are required).  With calculation set to manual, the event is required, and causes D3 to update

Comment: It doesn’t work for me though

Comment: So, there must be something else going on.  Without knowing what that is, we can't help

Comment: Ive figured it out. The linked cell converts all number as text, so I used the value function to correct it. I’m genuinely confused how you recreated my problem.